# Timestamp does not update with active date-time when HTML button is toggled in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var timeIn = new Date();

$(".BtnTime1").click(function() { 
    if ($(this).text() == "Green") { 
        $(this).text(timeIn); 
    } else { 
        $(this).text("Green"); 
    }; 
});

var timeOut = new Date();

$(".BtnTime2").click(function() { 
    if ($(this).text() == "Green") { 
        $(this).text(timeOut); 
    } else { 
        $(this).text("Green"); 
    }; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" border = "1px">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <td>Time-In Room</td>
 <td>Time-Out Room</td>
 <td>Time Difference</td>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td><button class = "BtnTime1 btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>
 <td><button class = "BtnTime2 btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>

 <td class = "TimeDiff"><br/></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody> 
 </table>
```

Hi, I have some jQuery code that calls classes ".BtnTime1, .BtnTime2", when a button is clicked/toggled it displays a timestamp. The issue is the timestamp does not update with the active date-time when the button is toggled. What have I done wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `timeIn` and `timeOut` values inside the click function:

```js
$(".BtnTime1").click(function() { 
    if ($(this).text() == "Green") { 
        var timeIn = new Date();
        $(this).text(timeIn); 
    } else { 
        $(this).text("Green"); 
    }; 
});

$(".BtnTime2").click(function() { 
    if ($(this).text() == "Green") { 
        var timeOut = new Date();
        $(this).text(timeOut); 
    } else { 
        $(this).text("Green"); 
    }; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" border = "1px">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <td>Time-In Room</td>
 <td>Time-Out Room</td>
 <td>Time Difference</td>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td><button class = "BtnTime1 btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>
 <td><button class = "BtnTime2 btn-danger btn-block btn-outline-dark">Green</button></td>

 <td class = "TimeDiff"><br/></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody> 
 </table>
```

Comment: @Taplar make sense. Accepted and updated it with that suggestion

Comment: Many thanks for your help and time Ankit! That seemed to do the trick!